# Delete objects (similar objects/duplicates) in coreData

Tags: core-data, duplicates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have in my entity an property named cardId.
Sometimes this cardId is more then once in my entity. I want to delete these duplicates.

How can I find these duplicates and delete them?

```
allObjects = [__fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
for (Entity *inbox in allObjects) {

    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:**objectToDelete**];
}
```

How can I find these similar objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just an idea, you have to elaborate it yourself.

You can specify to return only distinct results from your fetch with `setReturnsDistinctResults` of `NSFetchRequest` after specifying your key (cardId) as `propertiesToFetch`. So you make a first fetch of all distinct object and copy the result to a mutable array what I'll call `distinctArray`. Then you make a second fetch where you query ALL objects, thus with `setReturnsDistinctResults` disabled into `completeArray`. You iterate through the elements of `distinctArray` and remove each element from `completeArray`. What remains in `completeArray` will be the objects to delete.

The more low level implementation of this (probably more efficient as well) would be a double for cycle. You fetch only all objects in `completeArray` and do the old good double cycle:

```
NSMutableArray* objectsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:how_many_duplicates_you_expect];
for (int i = 0; i < [completeArray count]; i++) {
   for (j = i + 1; j < [completeArray count]; j++) {
      MOObject* objecti = [completeArray objectAtIndex:i];
      MOObject* objectj = [completeArray objectAtIndex:j];
      if (objecti.cardId == objectj.cardId) {
          [objectsToDelete addObject:objectj];
      }
   }
 }
```

At the end there will be all objects to be deleted in `objectsToDelete`. Pay attention, if you have more than two occurrences of the same object in your db, there might be duplicates even in `objectsToDelete` so check it before deleting.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. What would work is if instead of objectsToDelete being an NSMutableArray, make it an NSMutableOrderedSet so that objects are not repeated. Then you can iterate through the array and delete all the objects, without worrying about dupes in that array.

Comment: NSHipster has a good article on exactly what "for i in range awesome" is suggesting: http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/

Comment: Use NSMutableOrderedSet with care. If you have two managed objects with the same cardID and you fetch all objects for their entity then the fetch results will contain two _different_ objects having the same cardID and they will be inserted two times in the set. You should override isEqual method in your MO subclass to make NSMutableOrderedSet work correctly.